# send a command from one flow to another flow in node-red

Tags: node-red

I would like to use Nodered in our project. In order to make things simpler I am planning to create several flows and then send commands from one flow to other flow but I don't see any option to do this.

Is it possible at all and if so, could some one give me an idea to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the Link node, it will do exactly what you need

[image]